# Is any tensor sum of decomposables?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ be (not necessary finite dimensional) $\mathbb{R}$-vector space
and $TV$ is tensor power. (The vector space underlaying the tensor algebra)

Is any tensor $v\in TV$ a linear combination of decomposable tnsors, i.e.
is it a linearcombination of tensors like $v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_m$ for
$v_i\in V$ ?

Comment: Forget the tensor algebra part, it's direct sum of finite tensor powers, so it suffices to answer the question there. Then, the anwswer is yes, right? In fact, you can get a basis for $V^{\otimes k}$ by considering $\{e_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_k\}$ where $e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: Yes I'm just lookingon at the vector space. Can you write your comment as a formal answer, please?

Comment: You don't need a basis. The positive answer is essentially the definition of the tensor product.

Comment: @Cantlog Not if its not over a non-vector space.

Comment: Dear @AlexYoucis: this is true for any tensor product of modules: elements of $M\otimes N$ is a finite sum of $x_i\otimes y_i$. Or I misunderstand what you mean by "non-vector space"?